# NoReverseMatch at /polls/top/ Why does such a error happens?

Tags: python, django

I got an error,NoReverseMatch at /polls/top/ Reverse for 'detail' with arguments '(1,)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: [`'polls/top/<int:pk>/'`] .
I wrote in views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from .models import Polls
def top(request):
    data = Polls.objects.order_by('-created_at')
    return render(request,'index.html',{'data':data})

def detail(request):
    data = Polls.objects.order_by('-created_at')
    return render(request,'detail.html',{'data':data})
```

in child app's urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from . import views

app_name = 'app'
urlpatterns=[
    url('top/', views.top, name='top'),
    url('detail/<int:pk>/', views.top,name='detail'),
]
```

in parent app's urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls import url,include

urlpatterns = [
    url('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url('polls/', include('polls.urls')),
]
```

in index.html

```
<main>
            {% for item in data %}
                            <h2>{{ item.title }}</h2>
                            <a href="{% url 'polls:detail' item.pk %}">SHOW DETAIL
</a>

            {% endfor %}
</main>
```

When I access top method, the error happens.I really cannot understand why I cannot access item.pk.I rewrote pk,but same error happens.What is wrong in my code?How should I fix this?

My new urls.py is

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from . import views

app_name = 'app'

urlpatterns=[
    url('top/', views.top, name='top'),
    url('detail/<int:pk>/', views.detail,name='detail'),
]
```

My full traceback is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/xxx/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 35, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/xxx/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 128, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/Users/xxx/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/xxx/blog/app/views.py", line 7, in top
    return render(request,'index.html',{'data':data})
  File "/Users/xxx/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py", line 36, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
  File "/Users/xxx/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 62, in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request)
  File "/Users/xxx/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "/Users/xxx/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 175, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "/Users/xxx/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 167, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/Users/xxx/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 943, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/Users/xxx/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 910, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/Users/xxx/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 211, in render
    nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context))
  File "/Users/xxx/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 910, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/Users/xxx/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 447, in render
    url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=current_app)
  File "/Users/xxx/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/base.py", line 88, in reverse
    return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs))
  File "/Users/xxx/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 632, in _reverse_with_prefix
    raise NoReverseMatch(msg)
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'detail' with arguments '(1,)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: [‘polls/detail/<int:pk>/']
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve on the top view and detail view? They look mixed up.

Comment: You need to post the full traceback. The code you've shown wouldn't give this error.

Comment: @RamkishoreM top view shows all content's Polls.When I click `<a href="{% url 'polls:detail' item.pk %}">`,  program goes into detail view, and pick up clicked  Polls's model, and shows the model's detail in  detail.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add pk to detail view arguments

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

def detail(request, pk):
    poll = get_object_or_404(Polls, pk=pk)
    return render(request,'detail.html',{
        'poll':poll
    })
```

and on your urls.py you had views.top where it should be views.detail

```
urlpatterns=[
    path('top/', views.top, name='top'),
    path('detail/<int:pk>/', views.detail, name='detail'),
]
```

Comment: thank you for your answering.I wrote your code, but same error happens.How should I fix this?

Comment: we got one more issue to fix. I've added it to the post

Comment: thank you but still I got same error...If you know something, please help me

Comment: I updated my question.If you know something, please help me

Comment: changed url to path as in my snippet?

Comment: I changed url into pathos error is solved.Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

You're confused between the old and new way of specifying URL patterns. You're using the new way so you need to use `path` instead of `url`:

```
path('detail/<int:pk>/', views.detail, name='detail'),
```

Note also, you had `top` instead of `detail` as the view; in addition, your `detail` function has to accept that `pk` argument.

Answer (score -1):

If you want a view to accept some kind of parameter (which your url indicates you want to do), you have to set an argument for the view.

change

```
def top(request):
```

to

```
def top(request, pk = None):
```

Comment: thank you for your answering.I wrote your code,`def top(request,pk = None):
    data = Polls.objects.order_by('-created_at')
    return render(request,'index.html',{'data':data})` but same error happens.I doubt pk variable is not used in this method, so am I misunderstand your answer?